# ¿Por qué no puedo crear un botón toogle dentro de esta tabla y sólo me aparece el checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap, checkbox

Estoy creando una pagina que sirve como una planilla de asistencias, mi intención es que el usuario deslice un boton toogle para que posteriormente esos resultados sean almacenado en un array, pero al intentar crear el boton no me funciona y simplemente me queda un checkbox sin nada ¿cual es mi error?
agradeceria mucho a quien me pueda ayudar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Asistencia - Escuelas Newton</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-toggle-master/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/bootstrap.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/bootstrap.min.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-toggle-master/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js">
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Estilo.css">
<link rel="icon" type="text/css" href="Imagenes/icon.jpg">
</head>

<body background="Imagenes/Logox3.jpg" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-size: 100% 100%" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-lg-4">


<header>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
<hgroup>
<img src="Imagenes/logo3.png" style="background-attachment: fixed">
<h2 style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;;">Planilla de asistencias</h2>
</hgroup>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="margin-right: 
7px">
<div align="right">
<button class="btn btn-info">Ajustes</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger">Salir</button>
</div>
</div>
</header>

<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
<div class="main-row">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table" >
<thead class="thead-inverse">
<tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Alumno</th>
  <th>Estado</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">1</th>
  <td>Mark</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">2</th>
  <td>Jacob</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">3</th>
  <td>Larry</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
<button class="btn btn-success" style="margin: 3px;" onclick="guardarasistencia();">Guardar</button>
<strong><p class="help-block" style="color: blue; font-size: 16px; margin: 10px;">ATENCION: Asegurese de verificar los datos antes de guardar, una vez hecho click en el boton no podran ser modificados.</p></strong>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: te refieres a que el codigo de `button` no aparece? revisa si tienes algun javascript que podria estar ocultandolo

Comment: @juliocpiro
Sólo me aparece una casilla checkbox normal y lo que yo busco estaba convertirla en un botón toogle con boostrap.
insertó el código: input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">

pero no pasa nada.
quiero crear uno como los que aparecen aqui:http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todas las librerias de javascript ponlas asi:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

las pusiste mal, estan asi:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/bootstrap.js">
```

excepto la de jquery